# Appending text in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When changing the method to AppendText e.g. writeout.AppendText(firstline) I get StreamWriter does not support...

```
StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path);
        writeout.WriteLine(firstline);
        writeout.Close();
```

Instead of overwriting existing data in the text file, I want writeout to append "firstline" to the file

Comment: Everybody answered similar because of the easiness of the question. I wonder which answer will you confirm :)

Answer (score 4):

Change `StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path);` to `StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path, true);`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328969%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.

Alternatively you can use `File.AppendText`, e.g. `StreamWriter writeout = File.AppendText(path)`.

Or even just `File.AppendAllText`, e.g. `File.AppendAllText(path, firstline)`.

Answer (score 4):

You should create your StreamWriter with the explicit option to be able to APPEND to the file. Otherwise, it will always create a new one. Trying to call Append, when the StreamWriter wasn't created to append, gives the error you describe.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can do:

StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path, true);

to give the StreamWriter the ability to append.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second parameter of the StreamWriter constructor.
`StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path, true);`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

The boolean second parameter `appends` when set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Use the constructor `StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path, true);`

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate on what this actually does?

Comment: @Michael Skelton - It appends to the file when it is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path,true); //true indicates appending
        writeout.WriteLine(firstline);
        writeout.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the StreamWriter with an additional boolean parameter which specifies whether or not to append to an existing file:

```
StreamWriter writeout = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

Comment: How does this contain an extra parameter?

Comment: Simply by copying, pasting, forgetting to add the parameter and then editing the answer ;-)

Comment: Figured as much, just thought I'd tell ya xD

Answer (score 1):

Seek to the end of the stream first by setting StreamWriter.BaseStream.Position to the end of the stream and then continue as normal.

Answer (score 1):

What about using this?

```
var lines = new List<string>();
// load lines
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path);
    sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    sb.AppendLine("= = = = = =");
    sb.AppendLine(fileName + " ::::: " + time);
    sr.Dispose();
    if (sw == null)
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(Path);
    }
    sw.Write(sb.ToString());
    sw.Dispose();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```